# Determine all primes $p$ for which $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, quadratic-residues

> I need to determine all primes $p$ for which $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo p.

I think I'll need to use quadratic recprocity laws to do this, i.e., I need to need to find numbers $p$ where $x^2$ is congruent to $5 \bmod p$. I'm ok doing this for single values of $p$. But how do I find all primes for which this holds?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on where your investigation leads you, the answer to a question like this _could_ be a finite list of prime numbers. Or it _could_ be some kind of formula in $n$ that outputs all such primes sequentially. Or it _could_ just be another way to describe the set of such primes that is somehow more direct, like "all primes that are 3 modulo 8" or something similar. Without knowing where this will go it is not clear that it will literally be possible to "find" all such primes and write them all down.

Comment: The question just says "all primes". I don't think it'd be enough to say all primes p that are a quadratic residue of 5 lol

Comment: But would it be enough to say "all primes that are $\pm1\mod{5}$?

Comment: I can't see any other way it could be put lol. I'll just do this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Wikipedia article. Scroll up for review about quadratic reciprocity. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B15

Comment: Thank you!! The embarrassing part is I skimmed through that article a while ago. Guess I skipped over that important part! Thanks again

Comment: OK. So does the following make sense: since 5 is prime, the only quadratic residues of it are +/-1. Thus, if 5 is a quadric residue of p, then p is a quadratic residue of 5 which implies p is 1?

Comment: @Chloe.H I'm not quite sure I follow that. It is important that $5-1$ is divisible by $4$. That makes $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1$ for sure. So $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ exactly when $p$ is quadratic residue mod $5$, which happens exactly when $p$ is $1$ or $4$ mod $5$. (Aka $\pm1$ mod $5$.)

Comment: Right. But doesn't 5-1 divisable by 5 imply (5/p)(p/5) = 1 for p not equal to 2? because then 2-1 = 1 and (-1)^1 = -1

Comment: @Chloe.H Oh yes. Lots of things about primes work differently if it's $2$ we are talking about. For example, quadratic reciprocity ;)

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to verify that $\left(\dfrac{5}{p} \right) = \left(\dfrac{p}{5}\right)$. 
We know that $\left(\dfrac{p}{5} \right) =1$ when $p$ is quadratic residue modulo $5$.
So $p = 1\pmod 5$ or $4 \pmod 5$.
Therefore, for every prime $p$ in 
the arithmetic progression $1+5j, 5$ is residue.
Similarly, for every prime $p$ in the progression $4+5j, 5$ is residue.

We know from Diritchlet theorem that there are infinitely many primes 
any arithmetic progression $a+bj$, for fixed co-prime pair $(a,b)$. 
So just search for first few primes in the progressions $1+5j, 4+5j$. 
(You can see that first few primes with this property 
are $11, 41, 29$, ...etc).

To my knowledge, there is no algorithm that performs better than brute force technique for finding primes in the given arithmetic progression.