# Given two primes $p$ and $q$, $p = 2q+1$, $q \equiv 3 \mod 5$ is 5 a primitive root $\mod p$?

Tags: number-theory

So far:
From Fermat's Little Theorem I know that $5^{2q}\equiv 1 \mod p$. So 5's order in mod(p) has to be either 1,2,q, or 2q. **See note below**

The order can't be 1 because $5! \equiv 1 \mod p$.
I can rule out 2 in the same manner, because $p = 2q+1$ and $q \equiv 3 \mod 5$.
I don't know where to go from here. I'm pretty sure I have to use Legendre's symbol somewhere but I don't know where.

Thanks for all the help.

**Note:** OP had $p^{2q}\equiv 1 \mod p$. Changed it to $5^{2q}\equiv 1 \mod p$.

Comment: You mean 5^2q=1, instead of p^2q.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236083/determine-all-primes-p-for-which-5-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p

Answer (score 1):

Since $(q-1)/2$ is prime, a quadratic nonresidue mod $q$ is a primitive root. Now, use Legendre's symbol.

Comment: Why is (q-1)/2 prime? E.g. q=33 (p=67), (q-1)/2=16.

Comment: I bet he means $p$ instead of $q$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $p \equiv$ 2 mod 5 as $q \equiv$ 2 mod 5 and 2 $\times$ 3 = 6, 6 + 1 = 7 $\equiv$ 2 mod 5.

Also, we have that $q \equiv$ 1 or 3 mod 4 as $q \equiv$ 3 mod 5. Two cases:

If $q \equiv$ 1 mod 4, then $p \equiv$ 3 mod 4  (2(1) + 1 = 3).
If $q \equiv$ 3 mod 4, then $p \equiv$ 3 mod 4  (2(3) + 1 = 7 $\equiv$ 3 mod 4)

Then we have that

$(\frac{5}{p})$ = $(\frac{p}{5})$ by Gauss' Law of Quadratic Reciprocity.

Then $(\frac{p}{5})$ = $(\frac{2}{5})$ by the fact that $p \equiv$ 2 mod 5.

Finally, we have that $(\frac{2}{5})$ = -1 as 5 $\equiv$ -3 mod 8.

So 5 is a quadratic non-residue mod $p$.

Since $\frac{p−1}{2}$ is prime, a quadratic non-residue mod $p$ is a primitive root.