# Proving that an ideal is prime - is it correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, ideals

> I need to prove that although $X^2 + 3X +1 \in \mathbb{Z} [X]$ is irreducible, the ideals $(5,X^2 + 3X +1 )$ and $(11, X^2 + 3X +1)$ are not prime.

I know that an ideal $I$ is prime iff ${\mathbb{Z}[X]}/I$ has no zero divisors.

So when it comes to the first ideal, we have: ${\mathbb{Z}[X]}/(5,X^2 + 3X +1)={\mathbb{Z_5}[X]}/{(X^2 + 3X +1 )} = {\mathbb{Z_5}[X]} / {((X-1)^2 )}$.

That means that $X-1 + ((X-1)^2)$ is a zero divisor in the quotient ring so the ideal is not prime. Is that correct?

Similarly, for $(11, X^2 + 3X +1)$ we have that $X^2 + 3X +1 = X^2 -8X + 12 = (X-2)(X-6)$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[X]$.

> For what $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime is the ideal $(p,X^2 + 3X +1 )$ prime?

Could you help me a bit?

Comment: I think that you can't use the reduction criteria this way.

Comment: What you proved for $p=5,11$ is correct. For an arbitrary prime see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=2$, then $X^2+3X+1$ is irreducible modulo $p$.
For $p\ge 3$ one can write $X^2+3X+1=(x+3/2)^2-5/4=[(2X+3)^2-5]/4$ and your question reduces to the following: [Determine all primes $p$ for which $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236083/determine-all-primes-p-for-which-5-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p). (Maybe I had to say that $\mathbb Z[X]/(p,X^2 + 3X +1)\simeq(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 3X +1)$.)

> For what $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime is the ideal $(p,X^2 + 3X +1)$ prime? For $p\equiv 2,3\bmod 5$.

Comment: So if $5 \equiv a^2 \ \ mod \ p$ for $p$ prime, our polynomial is reducible and the factor ring has zero divisors. Thanks!