# Prove that 5 is a quadratic residue of an odd prime $p$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that 5 is a quadratic residue of an odd prime $p$ if $p \equiv \pm1( mod 10)$, and
that 5 is a non residue if $p \equiv \pm3 (mod 10)$.

Comment: Do you know quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236083/determine-all-primes-p-for-which-5-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p

Comment: That is not complete.And I dont like it

Comment: After we have used Reciprocity to conclude that if $p\ne 5$ then $(5/p)=(p/5)$, there is only minor calculation left to do. Are you looking for a solution that avoids Reciprocity?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a result of Fermat for which any prime number $p>5$ for which $-5$ is a quadratic residue is either of the form
$$ p=a^2 + 5b^2 $$
or of the form
$$ p=2a^2+2ab+3b^2,$$
hence $\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow p\equiv\pm 1\pmod{10}$ by direct inspection.

We are essentially using the fact that $h(-20)=2$.

My personal bible for such kind of questions is the book of *D.A.Cox, Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$.*