# Find $p$ : $p\mid k^2-5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Which odd primes can divide the integers of the form $k^2-5$ ?

My try:
odd prime means $p>2$
and if $$p\mid k^2-5$$
then $$k^2\equiv5 \mod p$$
hence 5 is quadratic residue mod p

Comment: Do you know about [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)?

Comment: If $p$ divides $k^2-5$ then $5$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

Comment: I did that already...after that how to find such all primes

Comment: See also: [Determine all primes $p$ for which $5$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236083).

Answer (score 2):

By quadratic reciprocity
$$\left(\frac5p\right)\left(\frac p5\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2\frac{5-1}2}=(-1)^{p-1}=1$$
Since $\left(\frac 5p\right)=1$, so is $\left(\frac p5\right)$, i.e. $n^2\equiv p\bmod5$ for some $n$. For this $n$ to exist, either $p=5$ and thus $n=0$, or $p=\pm1\bmod5$ since the nonzero squares in $\mathbb F_5$ are $\pm1$. Since $p$ is odd, we can refine the latter statement to $p=\pm1\bmod10$.

Thus, the *odd* primes dividing integers of the form $k^2-5$ are $5$ and those whose decimal representations end in $1$ and $9$.